concat two column in mysql , one of them is an auto-increments, using trigger
Dears, please below is my first trigger  to make a column as a concat a two column .. but it is not working ?! can i know where is the error
create table `concatcolumn`(
    `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key,
    `org` int(10),
    `orgid` int(20) -- this will be a concat column `org` and `id`);

delimiter $$
create trigger concatcolumn_after_insert
 AFTER insert on `concatcolumn`
  for each row
   begin
    set new.orgid = concat(new.org,new.id)
   end $$
delimiter ;



delimiter $$
create trigger concatcolumn_after_update
 AFTER update on `concatcolumn`
  for each row
   begin
    set new.orgid = concat(new.org,new.id)
   end $$
delimiter ;

enter image description here
even when I replace AFTER with BEFORE to be
delimiter $$
 create trigger concatcolumn_after_insert
  before insert on `concatcolumn`
   for each row
    begin
     set new.orgid = concat(new.org,new.id);
    end $$;
delimiter ;

I always get the id = 0;
enter image description here
any help please ?
filling the column orgid automatically by concatenate the org and id
regards

I guess you are getting 0 because the auto_increment value isn't assigned yet. You can not use AFTER because a error such as Can't update table 'concatcolumn' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. will be thrown

what does select version(); show?

10.4.32-MariaDB

Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your post to insert the data as editable content instead of images. See also how to ask.

note that mariadb and mysql are not the same product and have diverged significantly.  fortunately for you, since there is a solution to your problem for mariadb but not mysql :)

use a sequence instead of autoincrement; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78518364

thanks ysth ... i will this way for another table ... regards

CONCAT is a string operation.  Beware of confusing situations such as CONCAT(34, 5) = 345 and CONCAT(3, 45) = 345 also!

Another option would be using two triggers. The insert trigger would get the increment value from the information_schema.tables.
Trigger 1.
DELIMITER &&

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_concatcolumn BEFORE INSERT ON concatcolumn
 FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

   DECLARE autoId int;

   SElECT  auto_increment into autoId
   FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE table_schema = database() and table_name = 'concatcolumn';

   SET NEW.orgid = concat(autoId , NEW.org );
 END

DELIMITER ;  

Since you cant update same table in a function/trigger you need to get the auto_increment value from information_schema.tables.
MariaDB [test]> SElECT  auto_increment  FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = database() and table_name = 'concatcolumn';
+----------------+
| auto_increment |
+----------------+
|              4 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

I have declared autoId to save the auto_increment value which will bne used later on the set statement.

Trigger 2.
DELIMITER &&

 CREATE TRIGGER `before_update_concatcolumn` BEFORE UPDATE ON concatcolumn
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
     SET NEW.orgid = ( SELECT concat( NEW.id, NEW.org) FROM concatcolumn WHERE id = NEW.id )  ;
    END&&

DELIMITER ;  


thanks a lot Ergest Basha ... it is working , although I did not understand the first trigger well, hahaha

@Abd I have added an explanation, hope it is more understandable now.

thanks, my dear it is OK now ... regards

Instead of trigger you can use a generated column :
CREATE TABLE `concatcolumn`(
  `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `org` int(10),
  `orgid` TEXT AS (CONCAT(`org`, `id`))
);

INSERT INTO `concatcolumn` (`org`) VALUES (20), (21), (22);

SELECT *
FROM `concatcolumn`;

UPDATE `concatcolumn`
SET `org` = 200
WHERE `id` = 1;

SELECT *
FROM `concatcolumn`;


Neither MySQL nor mariadb allow you to use an auto increment column in a generated column

@ysth For PERSISTENT yes but it's ok with (default) VIRTUAL. Tested with mariadb.

@ErgestBasha https://sqlfiddle.com/mariadb/online-compiler?id=1b83c06f-9da1-465d-a7f5-eff014cacacb. The ubuntu version still allow it, and I also test on ubuntu... I'm supposed to delete my answer ?

@yotheguitou in fact you are right. I just tested on 10.6.15-MariaDB and it does allow it. The issue is with dbfiddle. The OP has tagget MariaDB so, your answer is valid.

dbfiddle shows it not working with 10.4 or 10.6; I see it does work with 11.4.   @ErgestBasha are you sure you got it working on 10.6?

@ysth 100%, just tested on my live MariaDB on openSUSE Leap 15.5

@ErgestBasha and what is the full select version(); there?

@ysth 10.6.15-MariaDB is complete version
